# Nano decimal is serialized in scientific notation in JSON, in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to return [Unit prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_prefix) as JSON from my C# code.

The problem is that I see this JSON in my browser:

[image]

I'm using `System.Text.Json` and not `Json.net`. What configuration should I use?

I'm trying to use that number in my calculations. Both in C# and in JS. I have stored them in my database and they are shown correctly there. Is scientific notation supported in calculations?

**Update**:

I tried to see the original response, and this is the JSON I get in my browser (without JSONView):

```
  {
    "id": 10,
    "key": "micro",
    "locale": "en",
    "title": "micro",
    "magnitude": 0.00000100000000000000,
    "relatedItems": {
      "modifiedViaList": true,
      "entityType": "Prefix",
      "module": "units"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "key": "nano",
    "locale": "en",
    "title": "nano",
    "magnitude": 0.00000000100000000000,
    "relatedItems": {
      "modifiedViaList": true,
      "entityType": "Prefix",
      "module": "units"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "key": "pico",
    "locale": "en",
    "title": "pico",
    "magnitude": 0.00000000000100000000,
    "relatedItems": {
      "modifiedViaList": true,
      "entityType": "Prefix",
      "module": "units"
    }
  },
```

But even in my `Network` tab I see scientific numbers, even using `HTTPie` I see scientific notation.

So, who is responsible for this formatting? How can I disable it?

**Update 2**:

This is my table in MariaDB:

```
CREATE TABLE `Prefixes` (
  `Id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Key` varchar(400) NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid(),
  `Locale` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Magnitude` decimal(40,20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IX_Prefixes_Unique_Key_And_Locale` (`Key`,`Locale`) USING HASH
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=41 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

And this is my `Prefix.cs` in C#:

```
namespace Units;

public class Prefix : IEntity, IKey, ILocale, ITitle
{
    public Prefix()
    {
        RelatedItems = new ExpandoObject();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Key { get; set; }

    public string Locale { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public decimal Magnitude { get; set; }

    public dynamic RelatedItems { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: [DO NOT use images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Copy the actual text from your code editor, paste it into the question.

Comment: Can you provide the model detail that you are binding JSON data with

Comment: @AnujKarki, question updated

Comment: Presentation layer "problem". Whatever view you are using is probably switching formats. As you can see in your raw json, it's as you expected. That means your client code shouldn't have problems using the values, given it supports that precision.

Comment: @JsonDimas What is the problem in having scientific notation? You can calculate with these numbers like normal, nothing special to do about.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that is a problem with your code - below you can see the responses that I get in FF and Chrome for such class:

```
public class Response
{

    public decimal ResultDecimal { get; set; }
}
```

Response FF:

```
{ resultDecimal: 1e-9 }
```

Response Chrome:

```
[{"resultDecimal":0.0000000010000000000}]
```

As you see both browsers format the response differently.
If you want to keep the same formatting in different browsers, I would suggest to use "string" instead of "decimal" data type.

Comment: _"If you want to keep the same formatting in different browsers, I would suggest to use "string" instead of "decimal" data type."_ What? Why? (Display-)Formatting is a UI-Concern.

Answer (score 1):

Follow Grzegorz Matysik's answer,I once met a similar issue,and solved it with a [customer converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0):

```
app.MapGet("/get", () => {
    return new Prefix
    {
        Title = "pico",
        Magnitude = 0.00000000000100000000
    };
    });

......




public class Prefix
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(DoubleConverter))]
    public double Magnitude { get; set; }
}


class DoubleConverter : JsonConverter<double>
{
    public override double Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        return reader.GetDouble();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, double value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString("0.00000000000000000000"));
    }

}
```

without the converter:

[image]

Apply the converter:

[image]

Comment: You have changed its format to string. That's not what I asked for.

Comment: When i debug,Magnitude attribute would always  be in format 1e-12 when I debug,although I assigned  0.00000000000100000000 to the property,that 's why I converted it to string